# What are all the relays and circuitry on the fuse box of a modern car for?

Tags: electronic-control-module, fuse-panel

I have a Peugeot comfort teepee that seems to be going senile and all the faults lead to the fuse box. It started with permanently on reverse lights. Intermittent windscreen wiper and headlights etc.

Answer (score 1):

The relays allow a small switch to control a large current.

The fuse box and relays are in one place as many connections are common and also make it easy to find the fuses - imagine having single fuses placed all over the car for each item.

Comment: I understand relays, mechanical and solid state. There are multiple chips on the board and I haven't looked them up yet but wondered what complex functions have been moved from the ecu to the fuse box and why?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the Tepee and you have your owner's manual, read it.

Comment: It's second hand and I don't think it came with one.

Comment: Without the owner's manual, you're left with a few alternatives for information; dealer or repair shop, Chilton or Haynes manual, subscription or public library to Alldata or Mitchell (USA) for online access to factory service manuals,  online search for free info, In general, engine and cabin fuse panels protect  electrical and electronics from overloading fused circuits. The alternator has its own fusible link wire to protect the battery against an internal short.